# How to make these simple javascript lines into a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just starting to learn javascript, and I've written the following code (coming from a php background):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#example-1").attr("rel","1");
$("#example-2").attr("rel","2");
$("#example-3").attr("rel","3");
});
```

I'm assuming that making it into something more like this would be faster and use less resources (even if it's miniscule):

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
foreach #example-X
 i++
        $("#exmaple-[i]").attr("rel","[i]");
    });
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Does php not have string concatenation ?

Comment: You probably want to use data() and not attr() for this.

Comment: rel is a valid html attribute, so it depends on what hes doing, but i would agree, data would probably suit his needs better, and Hunter, string concat is different in the two languages

Comment: Also, neither solution is clearly faster or more resource-efficient. The loop version is better because it leads to less code duplication.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I mainly wanted to decrease the amount of repeated code. Also, Rel attr is an attribute surely? that's why I thought to use that over data. Thanks guys.

Comment: `rel` is for `relation`, its main for link's and how the relate to the window, or stylesheets and what media type they relate to. `data` is really for any attribute you want to put on a DOM element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    for( var i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ) {
        $( '#example-' + i + ' .example' ).attr( 'rel', i );
    }
} );
```

and if you have more than three, assuming they are divs, i believe this should work

```
$(function() {
    for( var i = 1; i <= $( 'div[id^=example]' ).length ; i++ ) {
        $( '#example-' + i + ' .example' ).attr( 'rel', i );
    }
} );
```

Comment: You need to close the `$(`.

Comment: That looks good! but what if I want the example variable is actually (#example-1 .example), how can I replace the 1 for the i? so it detects #example-1 .example, and #example-2 .anotherthing?

Comment: Perfect! that is exactly what I was after. Javascript looks a bit more complicated than php that's for sure! Also can I ask why you just used $(function() as opposed to $(document).ready(function($)?

Comment: @user1202292 `$(function() {} );` is the shorthand version, that's all...

Comment: `$( function() { } );` is a shorthand notation of `$( document ).ready( function() { } );`

Comment: Thanks guys, you've been a massive help! I will have to give the right answer to Ascherer though as he answered about 8 seconds faster than you atoztoa! :P

Comment: Random downvote guy! Is there something wrong with this post? I'd love to fix it

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        $("#example-" + i).attr("rel", i);
    }
});
```

You can concatenate to create any string you need inside `$()`.

If you need `(#example-1 .example)`, then try

```
$("#example-" + i + " .example")
```